# python alexa result parsing with lxml.etree

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lxml, xml.etree

I am using alexa api from aws but I find difficult in parse the result to get what I want

alexa api return an object tree `<type 'lxml.etree._ElementTree'>`

I use this code to print the tree

```
from lxml import etree
root = tree.getroot()
print etree.tostring(root)
```

I get xml below

```
<aws:UrlInfoResponse xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/"><aws:Response xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11"><aws:OperationRequest><aws:RequestId>ccf3f263-ab76-ab63-db99-244666044e85</aws:RequestId></aws:OperationRequest><aws:UrlInfoResult><aws:Alexa>

  <aws:ContentData>
    <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">google.com/</aws:DataUrl>
    <aws:SiteData>
      <aws:Title>Google</aws:Title>
      <aws:Description>Enables users to search the world's information, including webpages, images, and videos. Offers unique features and search technology.</aws:Description>
      <aws:OnlineSince>15-Sep-1997</aws:OnlineSince>
    </aws:SiteData>
    <aws:LinksInCount>3453627</aws:LinksInCount>
  </aws:ContentData>
  <aws:TrafficData>
    <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">google.com/</aws:DataUrl>
    <aws:Rank>1</aws:Rank>
  </aws:TrafficData>
</aws:Alexa></aws:UrlInfoResult><aws:ResponseStatus xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/"><aws:StatusCode>Success</aws:StatusCode></aws:ResponseStatus></aws:Response></aws:UrlInfoResponse>
```

I use `root.find('LinksInCount').text` to get value of element but it does not work.

I want to know how to get the text `3453627` of `aws:LinksInCount`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run into two challenges:

- XML using namespaces
- two namespaces sharing the same namespace prefix

## XML document with reused prefix for 2 different namespaces

You see `"aws:"` prefix, but it is used for two different namespaces:

```
xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/"
xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11"
```

Using the same namespace prefix in XML is completely legal. The rule is, the later one is valid.

```
xmlstr = """
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<aws:UrlInfoResponse xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
  <aws:Response xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11">
    <aws:OperationRequest>
      <aws:RequestId>ccf3f263-ab76-ab63-db99-244666044e85</aws:RequestId>
    </aws:OperationRequest>
    <aws:UrlInfoResult>
      <aws:Alexa>
        <aws:ContentData>
          <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">google.com/</aws:DataUrl>
          <aws:SiteData>
            <aws:Title>Google</aws:Title>
            <aws:Description>Enables users to search the world's information, including webpages, images, and videos. Offers unique features and search technology.</aws:Description>
            <aws:OnlineSince>15-Sep-1997</aws:OnlineSince>
          </aws:SiteData>
          <aws:LinksInCount>3453627</aws:LinksInCount>
        </aws:ContentData>
        <aws:TrafficData>
          <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">google.com/</aws:DataUrl>
          <aws:Rank>1</aws:Rank>
        </aws:TrafficData>
      </aws:Alexa>
    </aws:UrlInfoResult>
    <aws:ResponseStatus xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
      <aws:StatusCode>Success</aws:StatusCode>
    </aws:ResponseStatus>
  </aws:Response>
</aws:UrlInfoResponse>
"""
```

Next challenge is, how to search for namespaced elements.

I prefer using `xpath`, and for it, you can use whatever namespace you like in the xpath expression, but you have to tell the `xpath` call what you meant by those prefixes. This is done by `namespaces` dictionary:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.fromstring(xmlstr.strip())

namespaces = {"aws": "http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11"}
texts = doc.xpath("//aws:LinksInCount/text()", namespaces=namespaces)
print texts[0]
```

Comment: Hi @Jan-Vlcinsky, do you know how to parse the "DataUrl" which is under "TrafficData"? and not to get to one under contentData? thanks!

Comment: @Yaeli778 what about `doc.xpath("//aws:TrafficData/aws:DataUrl/text()", namespaces=namespaces)[0]`