# Parsing Alexa XML with Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree, alexa-internet

I have a pretty similiar question to:
[python alexa result parsing with lxml.etree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382718/python-alexa-result-parsing-with-lxml-etree).

I'm wondering how to parse the second `DataUrl`. That means I want to get the `DataUrl` variable which is under `TrafficData` and not the one under `ContentData`. (get `people.com` and not `google.com`)

I'm also using lxml with the exact same data as he described.

Here is the code:

```
<aws:UrlInfoResponse xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
  <aws:Response xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11">
    <aws:OperationRequest>
      <aws:RequestId>ccf3f263-ab76-ab63-db99-244666044e85</aws:RequestId>
    </aws:OperationRequest>
    <aws:UrlInfoResult>
      <aws:Alexa>
        <aws:ContentData>
          <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">google.com/</aws:DataUrl>
          <aws:SiteData>
        <aws:Title>Google</aws:Title>
            <aws:Description>Enables users to search the world's information, including webpages, images, and videos. Offers unique features and search technology.</aws:Description>
            <aws:OnlineSince>15-Sep-1997</aws:OnlineSince>
          </aws:SiteData>
          <aws:LinksInCount>3453627</aws:LinksInCount>
        </aws:ContentData>
        <aws:TrafficData>
          <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">people.com/</aws:DataUrl>
          <aws:Rank>1</aws:Rank>
        </aws:TrafficData>
      </aws:Alexa>
    </aws:UrlInfoResult>
    <aws:ResponseStatus xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
      <aws:StatusCode>Success</aws:StatusCode>
    </aws:ResponseStatus>
  </aws:Response>
</aws:UrlInfoResponse>
```

Comment: If I need to delete the question and edit the linked one, please tell me, I am pretty new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to do :

```
namespaces = {"aws": "http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11"}
texts = doc.xpath("//aws:TrafficData/aws:DataUrl/text()", namespaces=namespaces)
print texts[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

***I've edited the answer as a whole***

In reply to your comment, all you need to do is change the `xpath`

Working example below (from the linked question) returns `google.com/`

```
from lxml import etree

xmlstr = """
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<aws:UrlInfoResponse xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
  <aws:Response xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11">
    <aws:OperationRequest>
      <aws:RequestId>ccf3f263-ab76-ab63-db99-244666044e85</aws:RequestId>
    </aws:OperationRequest>
    <aws:UrlInfoResult>
      <aws:Alexa>
        <aws:ContentData>
          <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">google.com/</aws:DataUrl>
          <aws:SiteData>
            <aws:Title>Google</aws:Title>
            <aws:Description>Enables users to search the world's information, including webpages, images, and videos. Offers unique features and search technology.</aws:Description>
            <aws:OnlineSince>15-Sep-1997</aws:OnlineSince>
          </aws:SiteData>
          <aws:LinksInCount>3453627</aws:LinksInCount>
        </aws:ContentData>
        <aws:TrafficData>
          <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">googly.com/</aws:DataUrl>
          <aws:Rank>1</aws:Rank>
        </aws:TrafficData>
      </aws:Alexa>
    </aws:UrlInfoResult>
    <aws:ResponseStatus xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
      <aws:StatusCode>Success</aws:StatusCode>
    </aws:ResponseStatus>
  </aws:Response>
</aws:UrlInfoResponse>
"""

doc = etree.fromstring(xmlstr.strip())


namespaces = {"aws": "http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11"}
texts = doc.xpath("//aws:TrafficData/aws:DataUrl/text()", namespaces=namespaces)
print texts[0]
```

Comment: The code you have wrote give me the first `DataUrl` which is under `ContentData`. I want to get the one under `TrafficData`. ( I know I can go to `texts[1]` but its not a good way to that in general. @duFF

Comment: Change the xpath to state you want the one under `TrafficData`, see above. I have never heard that using the index like stated is bad practice, especially with an API response that is unlikely to change regularly.