# Pythonic way to get a XML tree element in the same subtree with another element

Tags: python, xml

Is there a more elegant Pythonic way to get certain elements from xml tree that are in the same subtree than iterating with nested loops and ifs?

I.e. in pseudo SQL

```
select UsageStatistic/PageViews/PerUser/Value from Tree where UsageStatistic/TimeRange/Days=7
```

Here is a well formed subset of the XML response from Alexa Amazon AWIS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<aws:UrlInfoResponse xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/"><Response><OperationRequest><RequestId>dsfadf</RequestId></OperationRequest><UrlInfoResult><Alexa>
<TrafficData>
<DataUrl type="canonical">yahoo.com</DataUrl>
<UsageStatistics>

<UsageStatistic>
<TimeRange>
<Days>7</Days>
</TimeRange>
<Rank>
<Value>5</Value>
<Delta>0</Delta>
</Rank>
<Reach>
<Rank>
<Value>5</Value>
<Delta>0</Delta>
</Rank>
<PerMillion>
<Value>111,200</Value>
<Delta>-0.49%</Delta>
</PerMillion>
</Reach>
<PageViews>
<PerMillion>
<Value>11,442</Value>
<Delta>-1.71%</Delta>
</PerMillion>
<Rank>
<Value>7</Value>
<Delta>1</Delta>
</Rank>
<PerUser>
<Value>6.42</Value>
<Delta>-1.20%</Delta>
</PerUser>
</PageViews>
</UsageStatistic>

<UsageStatistic>
<TimeRange>
<Days>3</Days>
</TimeRange>
<Rank>
<Value>5</Value>
<Delta>0</Delta>
</Rank>
<Reach>
<Rank>
<Value>5</Value>
<Delta>0</Delta>
</Rank>
<PerMillion>
<Value>112,130</Value>
<Delta>-14.85%</Delta>
</PerMillion>
</Reach>
<PageViews>
<PerMillion>
<Value>11,314</Value>
<Delta>-13.39%</Delta>
</PerMillion>
<Rank>
<Value>6</Value>
<Delta>0</Delta>
</Rank>
<PerUser>
<Value>7.99</Value>
<Delta>+1.4%</Delta>
</PerUser>
</PageViews>
</UsageStatistic>

<UsageStatistic>
<TimeRange>
<Months>3</Months>
</TimeRange>
<Rank>
<Value>5</Value>
<Delta>0</Delta>
</Rank>
<Reach>
<Rank>
<Value>5</Value>
<Delta>0</Delta>
</Rank>
<PerMillion>
<Value>112,130</Value>
<Delta>-14.85%</Delta>
</PerMillion>
</Reach>
<PageViews>
<PerMillion>
<Value>11,314</Value>
<Delta>-13.39%</Delta>
</PerMillion>
<Rank>
<Value>6</Value>
<Delta>0</Delta>
</Rank>
<PerUser>
<Value>6.99</Value>
<Delta>+1.6%</Delta>
</PerUser>
</PageViews>
</UsageStatistic>

</UsageStatistics>
</TrafficData>
</Alexa></UrlInfoResult><aws:ResponseStatus><aws:StatusCode>Success</aws:StatusCode></aws:ResponseStatus></Response></aws:UrlInfoResponse>
```

Here is the code I got so far. It reads in the above response XML file as alexa_response.xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
prefix = "aws"
uri = "http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/"
ET.register_namespace(prefix, uri)
tree = ET.parse('alexa_response.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for a in root.iter("UsageStatistic"):
    for b in a:
        if b.tag == 'TimeRange':
            for c in b: 
                print c.tag, c.text
        if b.tag == 'PageViews':
            for d in b: 
                if d.tag == 'PerUser':
                    for f in d:
                        if f.tag == 'Value':
                            print f.tag, f.text
    print
```

Result:

```
Days 7
Value 6.42

Months 3
Value 6.99
```

I only need

```
Days 7 
Value 6.42
```

That is the PageViews/PerUser/Value/6.42 from the same subtree where the TimeRange/Days/7 is located.

And I wonder if there is a better way then iterate through with a number of nested loops and ifs?

Comment: Use `xpath()` in [lxml](http://lxml.de/) package that can compactly query node/attribute values.

Comment: Thanks Parfait, can you post an example or a sketch of how could I implement the "where" condition in that query?
I have seen this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382718/python-alexa-result-parsing-with-lxml-etree and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157705/parsing-alexa-xml-with-python

Comment: So I guess I can get that xpath approach working but how can I enforce that I am in the same subtree for both values coming of that single element queries?

Comment: Xpaths return one set of list at a time. So xpath twice. This returns value as list per the condition of 7 days: `tree.xpath('/UsageStatistic[TimeRange/Days="7"]/PageViews/PerUser/Value')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments and answers @max and @Parfait. I had to amend a bit to make it work so have to post it as my own answer.

```
prefix = "aws"
uri = "http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/"
import lxml.etree as lET
lET.register_namespace(prefix, uri)
doc=lET.parse('alexa_response.xml')
doc_root=doc.getroot()
for value in doc_root.xpath('.//UsageStatistic[TimeRange/Days="7"]/PageViews/PerUser/Value'):
    print value.text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  do this with a single XPath expression:

`//UsageStatistic/PageViews/PerUser/Value[../../../TimeRange/Days=7]`